# Maximum size of a single Script Property

Tags: google-apps-script

I know that the max size for Script Properties is 500K in total, but does anyone know the maximum size of a single Script Property? I am reading a spreadsheet, using Utilities.jsonStringify on it and trying to save to a Script Property, but I am getting an 'Argument too large' when I run ScriptProperties. The data is about 8k, and I am nowhere near the 500k limit.

Thanks in advance
Chris

Comment: There are better ways to store large amounts of data. And especially since it it JSON, you should consider using ScriptDb.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum properties size in Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41397711/what-is-the-maximum-properties-size-in-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Each property value has a maximum size limit of 9kB."

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/script_user_properties

You should really consider, as suggested by Srik and the documentation, use [ScriptDb](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb).

Comment: Thanks for your responses chaps.

Comment: Thanks for your responses chaps.   I am currently trying to improve performance on a UI app and have been loading spreadsheets upfront into arrays (and subsequently referencing records positionally which is super quick). This as you know is slow, so I have been looking at alternatives, including using ScriptDb. However I am ending up having to use multiple ad-hoc requests to get the data I need with ScriptDb, which results in no real performance gain.

Comment: My next test is to load upfront into an array from ScriptDb rather than spreadsheets (however this has the overhead of needing a sort to make the positional logic in my code work).    Anyway, thanks very much for your feedback.

Comment: As of November 2014, ScriptDB no longer exists.