# What is the maximum properties size in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to store large number of key/value pairs in Google Apps script and it fails after a while.  I am using this:

```
var properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
properties.setProperties(newProperties, false);
```

It works fine until around 10,000 and then it gets this:

**Exception: Too many arguments provided. Expected: properties. at getGroups (GroupCache:77) at warmCache (GroupCache:133)**

Is this the maximum size?  If so, is there a way around this?  I cannot use CacheService because there is no way to get all the values out (only retrieval is by key).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The page [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) states the following limits:

- Properties value size: 9kB per value
- Properties total storage:  500kB per property store

Additionally, there is a limit on the number of read/write operations per day: 50,000 for consumer accounts and 500,000 for G Suite Basic/Business/Edu/Gov.

A possible workaround is to use a spreadsheet to store data in. A spreadsheet can have up to 2,000,000 cells. A cell can hold a string up to 50,000 characters.