# Google Script: can I get all values of a cell (Text, Formula, Format, Font, Mergings, Orientation) as an array?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a way to "save" cells as an array. So that later on I can restore the cell with all its properties by using that array. Is this possible?

I assume I could go through all the .get commands from the range class. But I asume this would take very long. So is there a command to get everything at once?

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual expected value, how about using "Method: spreadsheets.get" of Sheets API? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) If that was not your expected value, I apologize.

Comment: Is it possible to then save this as a array or string?
For example that i can copy the output of spreadsheets.get to a cell in the file and later on get the code of this cell and restore the sheet with it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Is it possible to then save this as a array or string?`, I think that it is possible. And, about `For example that i can copy the output of spreadsheets.get to a cell in the file and later on get the code of this cell and restore the sheet with it?`, you can see a thread related to this situation at https://stackoverflow.com/q/51790433 But, in that case, I think that the size of value from Sheets API might be larger than 50000 bytes which is the maximum size in a cell. So, in this case, I think that the value can be saved to a text file.

Comment: Your question could be improved with an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Some sample data before, and what you would like stored.  What is "all it's properties"?  Are looking gor cell contents and formatting?  How many cells will you monitor?  How many versions? Also, Sheets logs certain changes.  Is there a specific [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) that you are trying to address?

Answer (score 0):

**Sheets Backup**

That's how I perform sheet backups and I store all of the 2d arrays in one object as json in ascii files.  My files are always kept simple.  I never use any formulas and I hardly ever use colors.  I don't worry too much about styling either so my objects may be much smaller than yours.  I tried using properties service but each each key in script properties is limited to 9 KB per key and a total of 500k see - [Properties Class Limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77319066/is-there-something-built-into-propertiesservice-that-is-supposed-to-detect-when). So I use ascii files instead.  I also store all of my [script backups](- [Script Backups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68929627/7215091)) in ascii files.

gs:

```
function backupSheets(shObj) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(shObj.ssid);
  const fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(shObj.fldrid);
  let dts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss");
  let subfldrName = Utilities.formatString('%s-%s', ss.getName(), dts);
  let subfldr = fldr.createFolder(subfldrName);
  let len = shObj.names.length;
  shObj.names.forEach((name,i) => {
    let n = i + 1;
    ss.toast(`Saving File: ${name} ${n} of ${len}`,'BackUp Status',10);
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    const rg = sh.getDataRange();
    let sObj = {};
    sObj["dvA"] = rg.getDisplayValues();
    sObj["nfA"] = rg.getNumberFormats();
    sObj["bgA"] = rg.getBackgrounds();
    sObj["fwA"] = rg.getFontWeights();
    sObj["fcA"] = rg.getFontColorObjects().map(r => r.map(obj => obj.asRgbColor().asHexString()));
    sObj["vaA"] = rg.getVerticalAlignments();
    sObj["haA"] = rg.getHorizontalAlignments();
    sObj["wstrategyA"] = rg.getWrapStrategies();
    sObj["cwA"] = [...Array(rg.getWidth()).keys()].map(i => sh.getColumnWidth(i + 1));
    sObj["rhA"] = [...Array(rg.getHeight()).keys()].map(i => sh.getRowHeight(i + 1));
    const c = JSON.stringify(sObj);
    const file = subfldr.createFile(`${name}.gs`, c, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
  });
  return shObj;
  ss.toast('EOF');
}

function loadSheetFromAsciiFile() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const r = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Enter Source File Id", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  const fileId = r.getResponseText();
  if (r.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK && fileId.length) {
    const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
    const sObj = JSON.parse(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
    sh.getRange(1, 1, sObj.dvA.length, sObj.dvA[0].length).setValues(sObj.dvA);
    sh.getRange(1, 1, sObj.nfA.length, sObj.nfA[0].length).setNumberFormats(sObj.nfA);
    sh.getRange(1, 1, sObj.bgA.length, sObj.bgA[0].length).setBackgrounds(sObj.bgA);
    sh.getRange(1, 1, sObj.fwA.length, sObj.fwA[0].length).setFontWeights(sObj.fwA);
    sh.getRange(1, 1, sObj.fcA.length, sObj.fcA[0].length).setFontColors(sObj.fcA);
    sh.getRange(1, 1, sObj.vaA.length, sObj.vaA[0].length).setVerticalAlignments(sObj.vaA);
    sh.getRange(1, 1, sObj.haA.length, sObj.haA[0].length).setHorizontalAlignments(sObj.haA);
    if(sObj.wstrategyA && sObj.wstrategyA.length > 0) {
      const wsObj = {"WRAP":SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.WRAP,"OVERFLOW":SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.OVERFLOW,"CLIP":SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.CLIP};
      let wstA = sObj.wstrategyA.map(r => r.map(e => wsObj[e]));
      sh.getRange(1,1,wstA.length,wstA[0].length).setWrapStrategies(wstA);
    }
    sObj.cwA.forEach((e, i) => sh.setColumnWidth(i + 1, e));
    sObj.rhA.forEach((e, i) => sh.setRowHeight(i + 1, e));
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    ss.toast('Process Complete');
  } else {
    ss.toast("Process Cancelled")
  }
}

function getSomeSheets(ssid) {
  console.log('getSomeSheets')
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  let shObj = {};
  const shts = ss.getSheets().map(sh => sh.getName());
  shObj['names'] = shts;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(shObj));
  return shObj;
}
```

It all starts with this dialog which allows you to enter spreadsheet id and folder id and select which sheets you wish to backup.  On the reverse you can pick any tab you wish to restore to.  I didn't make it to restore all at one time.

```
function launchBackupSheetsDialog() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("sheetBackUp"), "Backup Sheets Dialog");
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
  <style>
    input{margin:2px 5px 2px 0;}
    #btn3,#btn4{display:none}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        
        <input type="text" name="SpreadsheetId" placeholder="SpreadsheetId" id="ssid" size="50" onchange="getSheetNames();" />
    <br /><input type="text" name="FolderId" placeholder="Backup Folder Id" id="fldrid" size="50"/>
        <br /><div id="shts"></div>
        <br /><input type="button" value="Get Sheet Names" onClick="getSheetNames();" id="btn1"/>
    <br /><input type="button" value="0" onClick="unCheckAll();" size="15" id="btn3" />
    <input type="button" value="1" onClick="checkAll();"size="15" id="btn4"/>
        <br /><input type="button" value="Backup Sheets" onClick="backupSheets();" id="btn2" />
  </form>
        <script>
            function getSheetNames() {
        console.log('getSheetNames');
        let ssid = document.getElementById("ssid").value;
        console.log(`This the id ${ssid}`);
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler((shObj) => {
           document.getElementById('btn1').style.display = "none"; 
           document.getElementById('btn3').style.display = "inline";
           document.getElementById('btn4').style.display = "inline";
           shObj.names.forEach((name,i) => {
           let br = document.createElement("br")
           let cb = document.createElement("input");
           cb.type = "checkbox";
           cb.id = `cb${i}`;
           cb.name = `cb${i}`;
           cb.className = "cbx";
           cb.value = `${name}`;
           cb.checked = true;
           let lbl = document.createElement("label");
           lbl.htmlFor = `cb${i}`;
           lbl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${name}`));
           document.getElementById("shts").appendChild(cb);
           document.getElementById("shts").appendChild(lbl);
           document.getElementById("shts").appendChild(br);
        });
      })
        .getSomeSheets(ssid);
      }   

      function backupSheets() {
        let cbs = document.getElementsByClassName("cbx");
        let ssid = document.getElementById("ssid").value;
        let fldrid = document.getElementById("fldrid").value;
        let snA = [];
        for(let i = 0;i<cbs.length;i++) {
          if(cbs[i].checked) {
            snA.push(cbs[i].value);
          }
        }
        if(ssid && fldrid && snA.length) {
          google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler((obj) => {google.script.host.close();})
          .backupSheets({names:snA,ssid:ssid,fldrid:fldrid});
        } else {
          window.alert("Invalid or Data")
        }
      }

      function unCheckAll() {
        let btns = document.getElementsByClassName("cbx");
        console.log(btns.length);
        for(let i =0;i<btns.length;i++) {
          btns[i].checked = false;
        }
      }

      function checkAll() {
        let btns = document.getElementsByClassName("cbx");
        console.log(btns.length)
        for(let i = 0;i<btns.length;i++) {
          btns[i].checked = true; 
        }
      }
      console.log('ah3.html');
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

- [Array.methods()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)
- [Templated Html](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Backup Dialog:

[image]