Timed Triggers inconsistently freeze for 1-3 minutes
I'm having an issue with Google Apps Scripts timed triggers in my script.
I have a main function that processes and matches a ton of data (43k rows), so I'm using timed triggers to stop the process and restart where it left off. It saves its data in the properties service.
The function calls the set trigger function I've written (which sets a one-second trigger) and immediately stops itself.
Called trigger function:
// Function to set a timmed trigger to start the main function again. 
function setrebootTrigger() {
    //manageTriggers(); disabled to see if this speeds things up FYI it didnt :/

    //Set a time-based trigger to continue processing after 1 seconds
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('organizeData')
        .timeBased()
        .after(1000)
        .create();

    // logToSheet("Freeze process trigger created."); disabled currently not needed for debugging
 }

Whole script
No matter how long I set the trigger to 1 sec, 5 sec, 20 sec, 1/2 sec it takes around 1-3 min to activate the main function again. I've set logs to see if its stalling when it pulls the data where it left off and even had a log right after the main function starts every time and before it stops itself after setting the trigger and those two logs had a 1-3 min separation so it's to do with the trigger itself:
15/05/2024 11:58:13 AM: Batch update completed.
15/05/2024 11:58:15 AM: Properties updated. Ending current iteration of loop.
**15/05/2024 11:58:16 AM: freeze process trigger set, freezing process to avoid timeout
15/05/2024 11:59:30 AM: main function started!**
15/05/2024 11:59:31 AM: Set YouTube batch size to 50 and RoosterTeeth batch size to 1500.
15/05/2024 11:59:31 AM: Set desired show name: On The Spot
15/05/2024 11:59:32 AM: Processing new batch of YouTube rows from index 100 to 150.

15/05/2024 11:53:38 AM: Batch update completed.
15/05/2024 11:53:39 AM: Properties updated. Ending current iteration of loop.
**15/05/2024 11:53:40 AM: freeze process trigger set, freezing process to avoid timeout
15/05/2024 11:55:14 AM: main function started!**
15/05/2024 11:55:15 AM: Set YouTube batch size to 50 and RoosterTeeth batch size to 1500.
15/05/2024 11:55:16 AM: Set desired show name: On The Spot
15/05/2024 11:55:16 AM: Processing new batch of YouTube rows from index 50 to 100.

It's really inconsistent, when I pull up the triggers tab I can see it just sitting there doing nothing

PropertiesService has limitations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77319066/is-there-something-built-into-propertiesservice-that-is-supposed-to-detect-when

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#after(Integer)

after(durationMilliseconds)
Specifies the minimum duration (in milliseconds) after the current time that the trigger runs. The actual duration might vary, but won't be less than your specified minimum.

Considering the above, there isn't any malfunction regarding the behavior you are seeing.
When I use after() to create a trigger, I usually use 60000 (one minute), which generally runs at that time. When using smaller numbers, sometimes, I have to wait more than one minute to get the trigger activated, and a few times, it doesn't run at all. If you haven't had the problem of not having a trigger running at all, you have been lucky so far.

well shi-, thanks for the info Wicket.

In case anyone comes here with a similar issue ive thought a work around. For my program i incorporated a "function manager".
In essence in my code i have a program that have an on edit function that tracks input from users then based on where and what the edit starts different functions. The main function was processing around 86k rows of data and was the one having the timeout issue.
What i did was since it was already being processed in batches and using a trigger to restart itself i switched from using a trigger to using that function manager function.
now whenever that main function would start the manager one is called first (does some checks) then starts the main function, when the main reboots it calls the manager again (after saving where it was at in script properties) then the manager function checks if it's the second or further iteration of the main, if so it waits 2 seconds ( to prevent function overlap ) then recalls the main function again.


function manageMain() {
  logMatchToSheet("Starting manager")
 var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
 if (scriptProperties.getProperty('runOrganizeData') === 'false') {
    logToSheet("Process stopped by user.");
    return;
    }
 var isFirstBatch = scriptProperties.getProperty('isFirstBatch');
 //logToSheet(`first batch value is ${isFirstBatch} during function start`)
  if (isFirstBatch === `notStarted`) { // If not set, it's the first run
      scriptProperties.setProperty('isFirstBatch', 'true');
      isFirstBatch = 'true';
      organizeData();
      return;
    } 
  logToSheet("Sleeping for 2 seconds to prevent overlap");
  Utilities.sleep(2000);
  logToSheet("Restarting main function")
  organizeData();

}



